# В чем преимущество использования реактивного программирования в Java?

Tags: java, reactive

Пытаюсь понять преимущество использования объектов Flow из пакета concurrency. В своей практике, при работе в асинхронном режиме, использую очереди использую и старые Event и Listeners, при этом даже восьми ядерный процессор работает нормально. Как только переходим на reactive programming.  метод в котором Publisher отправляет сообщения подписчикам,  выжирает все потоки в ядрах, и блокирует исполнение других потоков.
Итак, в чем конкретное преимущество использования Flow,Vert.X, AKKA.
Вот приблизительный снипет.

```java
    SubmissionPublisher<Image> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>();  
    Subscriber<Image> sendImageToDataBase = new Subscriber1();  
    Subscriber<Image> sendImageToWebServices = new Subscriber2();  
    Subscriber<Image> sendImageToOCR = new Subscriber3();  
    Subscriber<Image> sendImageToProcess= new Subscriber4();  
    publisher.subscribe(sendImageToDataBase);  
    publisher.subscribe(sendImageToWebServices);  
    publisher.subscribe(sendImageToOCR);  
    publisher.subscribe(sendImageToProcess);  
    List<Image> listImages = List.of(/*More Images >Integer.Max_Value */);//Collections of  Images 
    for (Image img : listImages) {  
    listImages.forEach(publisher::submit); //method  submit  called 65000 
    times}  
    publisher.close();
```

есть огромное количество изображений которые должны отправляться 4-ем  потребителям. Дальше сервер умирает.

Comment: если все так плохо, может Вы как-то не так используете rx? будет понятнее если Вы выложите конкретный код.

Comment: `выжирает все потоки в ядрах` очевидно не используете [backpressure](https://blog.frankel.ch/backpressure-reactive-systems/) или неправильно для вашей задачи его сконфигурировали

Comment: Спасибо,  но разговор идет не о памяти, а о процессах. heap используется на 70% , но это не беда. Беда  в том, что все эти  подписчики создают новые потоки из пула потоков и пока не обработают все сообщения потоки не отпускают. Я могу ограничить количество потоков в jvm. Но смысл вопроса остался прежним- в  чем  преимущество  использования reactive?